# Pandas Data frame 2 dimensional array, to convert to a 3 dimensional array

Tags: python, pandas

```
def dataGen(x):
    x1=x/2
    x2=x/3
    x3=x+x1
    return x1,x2,x3
output3DArray=data_2D_ArrayDf.apply(dataGen)
```

Above is a code intended to create a 3 D array from a 2 D array. The input 2D array shape is [10,10] and expected output shape is [10,10,3] . Current output is just 2D 10,10 array of tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple workaround

```py
import numpy as np


def dataGen(a_2d_array):
    x, y = a_2d_array.shape
    output = np.zeros((x, y, 3))
    output[:, :, 0] = a_2d_array / 2
    output[:, :, 1] = a_2d_array / 3
    output[:, :, 2] = a_2d_array * 3 / 2
    return output


a_2d_array = np.random.rand(10, 10)
a_3d_array = dataGen(a_2d_array)
print(a_3d_array.shape)

# (10, 10, 3)
```

Comment: Yes Please imporve to it to 10,10,3 If possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pandas DataFrame is at best used to represent 2d data. Though it can do [multiindexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html), it is non-trivial for your case.

If you use numpy array though, this is very trivial

```py
def add_dim(x):
    return np.expand_dims(x, axis=-1) # <- axis=0 for (3,10,10) or -1 for (10,10,3)

X = data_2D_Array
output3DArray = np.concatenate((add_dim(X/2), add_dim(X/3), add_dim(X+X/2)), axis=2)
```

Numpy uses broadcasting to do the operations on all the elements of the array in parallel, and is extremely fast.

Comment: data_2D_Array=df.values() would be a Quick conversion to NP Array. How how to apply your solution. add_dim(x) ?

Comment: My bad, I missed the add_dim usage for each of these arrays. `add_dim` adds an extra dimension to all the arrays that you than concat the arrays on

Comment: Thanks,
is it possible to have (add_dim(X/2), add_dim(X/3), add_dim(X+X/2)) into a Function, so that we could have any custom transformation there. A function takes a double and returns 3 double

Comment: Yes. Just make sure you call the function on the whole array rather than it's elements. And the resultant `n` arrays should also all an extra dimension to concat on